# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.routes'

Tags: python, fastapi

So I'm learning fastapi right now and I was trying to separate my project into multiple files but when I do I get this error.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.routes'`

I have read [This](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/) multiple times and I'm pretty sure I did everything right can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

```
app
│   main.py
│   __init__.py
│
└───routes
        auth.py
        __init__.py
```

main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from app.routes import auth

app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(auth.router)
```

auth.py

```
from fastapi import APIRouter

router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/test")
async def test():
    return {"test": "test"}
```

I ran `uvicorn main:app --reload`

Comment: Change routes to routers as said in docs.

Comment: The directory is called routes though?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your uvicorn command is slightly off. From whatever directory is above `app` run --

```
uvicorn app.main:app --reload
```

Comment: I already tried that earlier and It didn't work it gives me ```ERROR:    Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "app.main".```

Comment: Double check your `__init__.py` is spelled correctly. I replicated your code successfully on ubuntu 18.01

Comment: I checked them twice. They both have nothing in them and I copy and pasted from the docs and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Does me using windows 11 have anything to do with this?

Comment: No, windows does not make any difference. For whatever reason python is not seeing it as a module. Maybe try from a terminal to see if it works? From the directory above `app` run `python3 -c 'import app.main'`

Comment: I tried from VScode terminal, cmd, PowerShell, and windows terminal and they were all the same. Running ```python3 -c 'import app.main'``` gives me ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.router'```

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with windows but this sounds like a path issue -- maybe try the following and see if it's resolved http://net-informations.com/python/intro/path.htm

Comment: Instead of `from app.routes import auth` in main.py what if you do `from routes import auth` have you tried this?

Answer (score 7):

Just run below command

export PYTHONPATH=$PWD

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I asked on github and I they were able to fix it.
Post: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/3602

Comment: Post the information about the bugfix here, just adding a link is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/3602, you just need to work at a higher level of your project.

## 3 Alternative solutions:

```
myproject/
└── app/
    ├── main.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── utils/
        ├── tools.py
        └── __init__.py
```

### 1. Use the full path (or relative path) on import

✅ `import .utils.tools` relative import works, but we should avoid that.

❌ `import utils.tools` doesn't work.

❌ `import app.utils.tools` neither.

✅ `import myproject.app.utils.tools` works fine for me.

### 2. Use an auxiliar file at the top level:

Add a simple proxy file at the same level of your `app` folder:

```py
#run.py
from app.main import app
```

```
myproject/
├── app/
│   ├── main.py
│   └── utils/
│       ├── tools.py
│       └── __init__.py
└── run.py
```

And run:
`uvicorn run:app --reload`

### 3. Make sure you are at the right path:

*Didn't work for me*

Simply `cd` to this level will probably solve.

```
cd myproject/
uvicorn app.main:app --reload
```